# symfony 2 forms default value (not preffered choice or empty_value)

Tags: forms, symfony

I have some problem. How set default value for choice or enitity form type ()?
I don't need prefffered choice or empty value. How to add this options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values are no options, it uses the second argument of the form constructor.

Comment: Yes, but my form class don't entity object. I have some filter with parameters.

Comment: The first sentence of your first comment seems to be lacking a word.

Comment: I have custom filters, for example type, area, rooms as array and city, region, district as entity. After search i want save filter values for next search.

Comment: When I said trying a simple array, I meant trying something like this : `array('type' => 'image', 'area' => 'jungle', rooms => array('room1', 'room2', 'city' => new City('Paris')));`

Comment: Thanks, but I done this save filter using js and url parameters :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `data` option. Details are in the [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#data).

Comment: do you know anything about the `empty_data` option for form fields? I'm not sure if this question is looking for that, but I am, and I can't get it to work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792285/symfony-form-field-attribute-empty-data-ignored